# How do I solve this question using vectors?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

Given trigonometric equation

$$5\cos \theta -12\sin \theta = 13$$

I'll be trying to determine a general solution using **vectors**. I've recently asked this question two times. However, the answers weren't genuinely understandable in particular. This way would also collide with other ways being used to solve this problem.

Regards!

Comment: I can't see an obvious way to do it using vectors, but you can divide by $\cos\theta$ to get $$5-12\tan\theta=13\sec\theta$$ and then $$169(1-\tan^2\theta)=144\tan^2\theta+25-120\tan\theta$$ and go from there.

Comment: You have asked this question, or an equivalent one, three times before. Divide by $13$ and look at this as a dot product equation: $\left(\frac5{13},-\frac{12}{13}\right)\cdot(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))=1$.

Comment: @robjohn I couldn't get it properly. Hence, I multiposted the same question.

Comment: Is there anyone who's able to make this question clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $5\cos\theta - 12\sin\theta = 13$ is equivalent to the vector equation
$$\left< 5, -12 \right> \cdot \left<\cos\theta, \sin\theta\right> = 13$$

Now in general, for any two vectors $\textbf{u}, \textbf{v}$ the dot product obeys
$$\textbf{u} \cdot \textbf{v} = |\textbf{u}| |\textbf{v}| \cos\phi$$
where $\phi$ is the angle between the two vectors $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$.  In this case, we have $\textbf{u}= \left< 5, -12 \right>$ with $|\textbf{u}| = 13$, and $\textbf{v} = \left<\cos\theta, \sin\theta \right>$ with $| \textbf{v} | = 1$, so
$$(13)(1)\cos\phi = 13$$
which means that $\phi = 0$.  In other words, $\left<\cos\theta, \sin\theta\right>$ is a unit vector that points in the same direction as $\left< 5, -12 \right>$, so $\theta = \arctan \left( - \frac{12}{5} \right) $.

Answer (score 1):

$$\langle 5,-12 \rangle \cdot \langle \cos\theta,\sin\theta \rangle = 13$$
$$\left(\sqrt{5^2+12^2}\sqrt{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}\right)\cos(\theta-\tan^{-1}(-12/5)) = 13$$
$$\cos(\theta+\tan^{-1}(12/5)) = 1$$
$$\theta = 2\pi k - \tan^{-1}(12/5), k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 1):

We know that given two vectors $u$ and $v$

$$u\cdot v=|u||v| \iff v=ku$$

therefore let

- $u=(5,-12)\implies |u|=13$
- $v=(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)\implies |v|=1$

therefore since $u\cdot v=|u||v|$ we have that

$$v=(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)=k(5,-12)=\left(\frac5{13},-\frac{12}{13}\right)$$

that is

- $\cos \theta=\frac5{13}$
- $\sin \theta=-\frac{12}{13}$

and

- $\tan \theta =\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}=-\frac{12}5$

from which we obtain

$$\theta = \arctan(-12/5) \color{red}{+2k\pi}$$

Note that we take $+2k\pi$ since $\cos \theta>0$ and $\sin \theta<0$.

Comment: Could you explain this step? $v=(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)=k(5,-12)=\left(\frac5{13},-\frac{12}{13}\right)$

Comment: Yes of course, I wasn't clear on that. Since $v=ku$ with $k>0$  we have that $|v|=k|u|$ and therefore $k=|u|/|v|=1/13$.

Comment: Great explanation :) I've also realized that this represents the triangle whose lenghts are $5-12-13$ respectively. What if we had an equation such that $5\cos \theta+6\sin\theta = 14$ or $5\cos \theta+6\sin\theta = 2\sec \theta$? What I mean by those equations is whether we're able to use the same method.

Comment: For this kind of equations $a\cos \theta+b\sin\theta = c$ we can use that [LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Tangent_half-angle_substitution) or [LINK2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Linear_combinations)

Comment: Can we also use this method? In other words, what kinda equations can I apply this method?

Comment: To apply that method we need $uv=\pm|u||v|$, that is u and v must be multiple.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple? Can you illustrate?

Comment: Multiple means $v=ku$ therefore $u\cdot v= |u||v|$ for k>0 or $u\cdot v= -|u||v|$ for k<0.

Comment: Let's consider $\cos^2(a) + \cos(a) = \sin^2(a)$. I'm going to be trying to apply this method. Since $u\cdot v=|u||v| \iff v=ku$, let $u = (1,1,1) \implies |u| = 1$, $ v=[\cos^2(a), \cos(a), \sin^2(a)]\implies |v|=1$. How does this approach seem?

Comment: Note that $u=(1,1,1)\implies |u|=\sqrt{1^2+1^2+1^2}=\sqrt 3$, maybe at first you should revise the basic definition for vectors.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! Let me try to proceed further. What about $v=[\cos^2(a), \cos(a), \sin^2(a)]\implies |v|=1$? This is where I was mostly stuck.

Comment: We have that $|v|=\sqrt{\cos^4 a+\cos^2 a+\sin^4 a}$ which is in general such that $|v|\neq 1$. For example for $a=0\implies v=\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Hold on. We have that $u=(1,1,1)\implies |u|=\sqrt{1^2+1^2+1^2}=\sqrt 3$ so $u$ is defined. However, why can't we define $v$? If $u\cdot v=|u||v|$, it yields $v=[\cos^2(a), \cos (a), \sin^2(a)]=k(1,1,1)$

Comment: Because |v| depends upon $a$ in that a case, whereas for $w=(\cos a, \sin a)$ we have $|w|=1$ for thye fundamental identity $\cos^2a+\sin^2 a=1$ fro all $a$.

Comment: Then how can we proceed? I only have that $k=|u|/|v|=\sqrt 3/|v|$. In other words, how would we define $|v|$?

Comment: Are you required to solve the equation by vectors? Maybe you could create a separate OP for that since comment are not suitable for that.

Comment: Okay, I will post a new question. Hopefully, you can share your dear thoughts by answering.

Comment: I've just posted a question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a geometric solution to the similar equation

$$5\cos\theta+12\sin\theta=13$$

From the Pythagorean triple $5$-$12$-$13$ construct the right triangle $\triangle ABD$ with sidelenghts $AB=5$, $AD=12$, and $BD=13$. Pick a point $C$ lying on $\overline{BD}$ such that $\overline{AC}$ is perpendicular to $\overline{BD}$. By the [Inscribed Similar Triangles Theorem](https://www.ck12.org/geometry/inscribed-similar-triangles/lesson/Inscribed-Similar-Triangles-BSC-GEOM/), $\triangle ABD$ is similar to $\triangle CAD$, therefore $\angle ABD=\angle CAD$.

[image]

Now for some trigonometry: Let $\theta=\angle ABD=\angle CAD$. Then $BC=5\cos\theta$ and $CD=12\sin\theta$. By construction, $BD=13$. Therefore,
$$BC+CD=BD\iff 5\cos\theta+12\sin\theta=13$$
By the Inscribed Similar Triangles Theorem, $\triangle CBA$ is similar to $\triangle ABD$, yielding the proportion
$$\frac{BC}{AB}=\frac{AB}{BD} \iff \frac{5\cos\theta}{5}=\frac{5}{13}$$
$$\implies \theta=\cos^{-1}(\frac{5}{13})$$

Maybe you can rearrange this setup to match your equation $5\cos\theta-12\sin\theta=13$.